Live reload a shared Typescript Library during React + Firebase development
I am working on a small React + Firebase app and I am implementing some backend functions through firebase functions. There are some shared datatypes and logic between the front end and backend and, to avoid repeating myself, I created a shared typescript library containing them. I am using vite and use it to run the development server. To host functions, I use firebase emulators as follows: npm run build  -- --watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions". In both of these cases, the frontend or the functions update as I save changes. However, this is not the case when I update the shared library. Is there a way I can configure the project so that changes to the shared library are also automatically updated as I save them?
A simplified directory layout for my project is as follows:
-functions:

package.json
src

-shared (the shared library):

package.json
src

-src
package.json
